# stop git from looking in previous dirs

Tags: git, status, subdirectory

i have a git repo on my home directory, where i manage some dotfiles and stuff. in the `.gitignore` file, I have the Desktop folder, so it doesn't get involved in the git repo.

when i am in the Desktop folder, even though there is no `.git` repo, when i type `git status`, i get this

```
% git status  
 On branch master  
 Changes to be committed:  
   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)  
    modified:   ../.zsh/misc.zsh  
 Untracked files:  
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  
    ../.irbrc
```

I would like it if git didn't look in my home folder, and look just in `pwd`, nowhere else.

how can i do that?
thank you.

Comment: well, i actually wanted to have zsh let me know if there is a git repo pwd. i guess i will just check if there is a .git dir.. thanks to all of you.

Comment: So you make your home directory a git repository (i.e. there is `.git` inside your home directory)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to run `git init` from your Desktop folder, which creates an empty Git repository at `~/Desktop/.git`. You don't have to ever commit anything to it. But, it will stop Git from traversing upwards through the directory tree when you type `git status`.

Or, simply avoid typing `git status` from within your Desktop folder. It's not a Git repository anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

Git isn't looking in your `~/Desktop/`, if it's in your `.gitignore`.

Judging from the locations of the edited files, I'm guessing that you've got a git repository in your `~`. If you `touch ~/Desktop/testfile`, `cd ~/Desktop`, `git status`, you shouldn't see it listed under `Untracked files:`, because everything in `~/Desktop` is being ignored.

**However**, you've called `git status` **while inside a git repository** - the one located (I'm guessing) in your `~`. Git is just looking in the repository you're in while you issue the `git status`, while ignoring everything in the `Desktop` directory from the `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like it if git didn't look in my home folder, and look just in pwd, nowhere else.

If `pwd` is inside your home folder and your home folder is a git repository, then git will look the repository (your home folder) even if `pwd` is one of the entry in `.gitignore`.

If I were you, I would not make my home folder a git repository because everywhere inside my home folder will be part of the git repository. If I need to put my dotfiles into a git repository, I will put the files in a separate folder, make the folder a git repository, and create symlinks to the files inside the folder from the home folder. It's not beautiful but it would not make my home folder a git repository.